# Not receiving result it seems with "onActivityResult()"

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have two activities, one just has a huge list view, the other has a plainText and button.

This "newRoll" activity needs to return a string which is added to an ObservableCollection, I haven't implemented the part where the listView updates but using logcat, I can tell that nothing is being added to the ObservableCollection that holds all items. Is there something I misunderstood about how intent works, from what I get this should work?

Main Activity:

```
    //upon clicking any item in the listView this runs:

    Intent NewRoll = new Intent(this, typeof(NewRoll));
    StartActivityForResult(NewRoll, requestCode);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            //just holds the string
                    holder = data.GetStringExtra("roll_name");
            //adds it to an observable collection
                    rolls.Add(holder);
            //me trying to get something back
                    Log.Info(rolls.Count.ToString(), "Roll Added");
                    Log.Info(holder, "Please?");
        }
```

NewRoll:

```
//on button click
//get whatever is in the plaintext
                newRoll = rollName.Text;
                data.PutExtra("roll_name",newRoll);
                SetResult(Result.Ok, data);
                Finish();
```

Comment: I'm quite certain the method signature has to be `protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)`

Comment: There's nothing to override, I then get the error "no suitable method found to override"

Comment: What kind of Activity class do you derive your activity from?

Comment: a simple "Activity" class, Android.App.Activity

Comment: OP is asking about Xamarin.Android in C#, not Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation at [Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.OnActivityResult/) states that the signature for Android.App.Activity.OnActivityResult is

```
[Android.Runtime.Register("onActivityResult", "(IILandroid/content/Intent;)V", "GetOnActivityResult_IILandroid_content_Intent_Handler")]
protected virtual Void OnActivityResult (Int32 requestCode, [Android.Runtime.GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
```

So you have to override that to receive the activity result like

```
protected override Void OnActivityResult (Int32 requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Yep my bad, the mistake was not calling the method correctly with override, as well as then making a small spelling mistake, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        //just holds the string
                holder = data.GetStringExtra("roll_name");
        //adds it to an observable collection
                rolls.Add(holder);
        //me trying to get something back
                Log.Info(rolls.Count.ToString(), "Roll Added");
                Log.Info(holder, "Please?");
    }
```

I do not see `@Override` annotation here. Are you sure you are overriding the `Activity` Base class method `onActivityResult`?